# No mouse cursor in Qt EGLFS on Yocto

Tags: mouse, qt, yocto

I am trying to use mouse cursor in Qt5 application.

When I run ./Qt5_CinematicExperience :

```
Failed to move cursor on screen HDMI1: -14
Could not set cursor on screen HDMI1: -6
```

There is no mouse cursor displayed on the screen.
Same results with another Qt5 application.
The click event seems to be working.

I am using Yocto rocko on kernel 4.14.24.

Do you think Qt5 needs a specific library to use mouse?

My mouse is present as input device in /dev/input/.
A cat command on /dev/input/event1 displays a lot of characters when I move the mouse.